# adb: failed to open app.apk: Operation not permitted with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, adb, apple-silicon, platform-tools

I am facing this issue when trying to run any flutter app on android emulator or physical device. It fails while executing adb command for installing the application.

```
 Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
 Performing Streamed Install
           
 adb: failed to open /Users/mohitsingh/Desktop/testapp/testapp/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Operation not permitted
 Warning: Failed to install APK.
```

However if I run the same command manually, It fails with the same error for the first time after app is built with `flutter build apk` command but it is successfully installed on subsequent trials with

```
adb -s emulator-5554 install build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
```

All other commands of adb seem to work fine. It was working fine till last week but this error started coming up suddenly with adb.

Comment: @Robert done. I've added the error and app installation command.

Comment: @Robert It is already turned off for the emulator, and I also tried it with a physical device, It's still having the same issue. The strange thing is that this error arises only when trying to install after the first build but installs correctly on subsequent tries.

Comment: Looking at the error message I am very sure that this problem is caused on client side (on MacOS). adb simply seems to be unable to access the apk file to be installed. So I see two possibilities: 1. adb doesn't have read permission to that file (on macOS you need to authorize programs to access files in your home dir). 2. may be because of rosetta emulation the path is somehow wrong and the file doe not exsit at all on the path adb want's to access.

Comment: 1) adb seems to have required permissions as running the command manually, it works most of the times. 2) If I build an app with flutter build apk, and then try to install it, it still gives the error for the first time but on subsequent tries, the install is successful. So, I'm not sure if this is the issue either. Another thing I noticed today is that native android apps are built and installed just fine and it seems to be the case with flutter apps only. If it is the second issue, is there any way to verify or debug it?

Comment: Do you have anti-virus installed? Some virus scanner also scan mobile apps and as you build the app it had never been seen before on any other system so the cloud based scanner may block access the first time until the cloud analysis is complete (which can take some seconds or minutes).

Comment: Don't have any virus scanner but it's a company laptop and they do have endpoint protector installed. It shows a dialog that file transfer is reported. The IT team says that it's just a reporting, more like a log. Nothing is blocked by it.

Comment: Hey @Robert I noticed one more thing. After building the app, both adb install and push fail with operation not permitted in the build folder containing app. But on subsequent tries, they all succeed. Is there any method to find out it's reason? Like is there any log created by adb tool itself?

Comment: I don't know MacOS enough to answer this . You may better ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com and include all details on your system hardware, MacOS version, installed security software and emphasize that what you ask is a MacOS problem, not an Android or development problem/question.

Answer (score 0):

**Error: ADB exited with exit code 1** is a common error
Here are the following solutions for that

**Solution 1**

add `android:exported="true` in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
android:exported="true"
```

**Solution 2**

> Turn on **Install via USB** in developer mode.

run the following Command

> flutter clean
>
> flutter pub
>
> flutter run

Comment: android:exported="true" is already there. Solution 2 also doesn't seem to work. Install via USB is already turned on in physical device and it's default in emulators as well.

Comment: Do you debug your app on a different device? Sometimes  the device blocks the installation process and mark the application as malicious software

Comment: Nope, I usually debug it on emulator only. But suddenly this problem started coming up since last 2 weeks.

Comment: Try it on another physical device sometimes your mobiles security protocol block the app installation and mark the application as malicious software

Comment: Already tried. Doesn't work. I've mentioned more details in the comments under the post. Please check them if you have some time.